# Storyboards - how to perform segues automatically without animation and showing the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, segue

I have an application where the user has to enter some information on the initial screens, such as the login credentials. All the navigations are done using a storyboard and segues, which automatically sets the navigation bar on top.

I have two storyboards that share the same controllers, so I use the same name for the segues (ipad and iphone versions).

So when the user comes back to the application, I read the core data and know that he has already performed the initial steps, so I would like to "skip" those screens.

Problem:
I can only execute the segues after the view is visible, otherwise the navigation is screwed up. But when doing so, the user sees the screen briefly and sees the animation "pushing" that screen away. I'd like to keep the navigation history on the navigation bar, that is why I want to use the segues and all the logic associated with them.

All the solutions point to creating the views programatically and putting them on the stack, but I'd like to take advantage of the storyboards.

Comment: try using performSegueWithIdentifier specifying the segue you want to "chain" to based on the authentication status. As for screwed up navigation, not sure i understand why it would be if you've set up your storyboard correctly

Comment: We're already doing the performSegueWithIdentifier, the issue is that it can only be performed on the viewDidAppear event, and not early like the viewDidLoad. That means the user is already viewing the screen and will notice the transition. If you try to do it on the viewDidLoad, the navigation is screwed (if you check the console some warning are present).

Comment: i'm nos sure i follow why the segue can only be performed in view did appear. Lets say you have a login controller, you perform the login, and at that point you perform the desired segue. This would happen as part of the authentication, not the view did load. I guess i'm confused about your line that reads "so when the user comes back to the application", can you explain more or show code?

Comment: Ok, let me try to simplify the question. I have two screens, and the user navigates from the first one to the second when he presses a button. A performSegueWithIdentifier is executed, and the second screen appears sliding in from the right (push). In certain cases, I'd like to skip the first screen and go directly to the second one, but if the users wishes, he may press the back button and go back to the first screen. So what I am doing is the performSegueWithIdentifier on the viewDidAppear. That causes the navigation to happen but the screen transition is visible.

Comment: If I try to do it on the viewDidLoad, which would be the perfect timing, it still navigates but the "back" button from the second screen does not work as I have navigated before the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it;

In your StoryBoard, assign an identifier to the second view controller (this is done on the identity inspector, setting the Storyboard ID field). In the code below, i have named mine secondVC;

Then in the viewDidLoad for your first controller (the one you want to skip but come back to) do something like this;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   /// validate  viewController one being displayed
   if(dontDisplayFirstController){

      UIStoryboard *storyBoard = self.storyboard;
      UIViewController *targetViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondVC"];
      UINavigationController *navController = self.navigationController;


      if (navController) {
        [navController pushViewController:targetViewController animated:NO];
      }
   }
}
```

This will efectivly push to the second viewController whilst still maintaining viewController one in the navigation tree.

Comment: I have the same issue as the OP; as well as constructing the correct navigation stack I also want to actually execute the prepareForSegue: method on the topmost view controller (it sets some properties the pushed VC requires.) I know I could do this "manually" after I instantiate the new VC, but I want to avoid duplicating the logic from the original prepareForSegue.